SQL Server linked servers vs. views
Is it possible in SQL Server 2019 to hide/block access to linked servers while still allowing the ability to read data from a view created based on a given linked server?
I tried setting up login mappings to the remote server, but this method blocks the user from being able to read data from the view.

create a view that reads data from the linked server
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS
SELECT * FROM [LinkedServerName].[DatabaseName].[Schema].[TableName];

Next, set up login mapping so that the view can access the linked server without giving users direct access
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = 'LinkedServerName',
    @useself = 'false',
    @locallogin = NULL, 
    @rmtuser = 'RemoteUser',
    @rmtpassword = 'RemotePassword';

Grant SELECT permission on the view to the user who needs access
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.MyView TO [YourUser];

Then, block the user from accessing the linked server directly
DENY ALTER ANY LINKED SERVER TO [YourUser];

Finally, if needed, hide the linked server from being listed
DENY VIEW ANY DEFINITION TO [YourUser];

